# Jquery Plugin for tree grid processing data on the server side?

Tags: jquery, html

I need a jquery plugin that loads the data into a tree grid processing these data on the server side, with a return JSON with ajax requests.

The idea that this plugin works like this:

http://www.igniteui.com/pivot-grid/overview

Does anyone know if there is any solution for free?

Comment: maybe you heard of `jqgrid` search for it and its "FREE".

Answer (score 0):

If you're only talking about how to implement the tree, then, jsTree is a good option. After that you can just build a gridview of your own, or use jquery dataTables plugin, and link the both together.

http://www.jstree.com/

http://datatables.net/

But I don't understand why you can't download and use the one you mentioned.